# What exactly happens when I go to www.example.com/abc

Tags: php, apache, redirect

until recently I thought www.example.com/abc points to a directory which resides at web directory which is /var/wwww/html (for fedora). When I installed phpmyadmin through 'yum install' I couldn't find any phpmyadmin directory in /var/www/html but I can still access www.example.com/phpmyadmin. What exactly happens when I go to www.example.com/abc? where is this routing defined? in httpd.conf?? what happened when i installed phpmyadmin? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

search for

```
/etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf
```

&

```
/usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

as said in conf:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

Answer (score 0):

/phpmyadmin in this case is an Alias that points to a directory in /usr/share (e.g. /usr/share/phpmyadmin)